# Using a dataframe's name as string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have problems converting the variable into a string. It doesn't work with str(object), this prints out the dataframe instead.
I labelled my dataframe as Apple:

```
Apple = pd.Dataframe()
```

Then I was trying to do a for loop to save the the data into another dataframe. So i did it by:
First, I stored the stocks in apple_stock_list, [Apple, Samsung]
Then I wanted to do a for loop like this:

```
for stocks in apple_stock_list:
    for feature in features:
        apple_stock[str(stocks) + "_"+ feature] = stocks[feature]
```

However, str(stocks) does not change stocks into "Apple". Is there anyway I could get the Dataframe's variable name to be a string?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Considering the following df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

apple = pd.DataFrame(data=np.ones([5,5]))
```

As [@Georgy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237029/using-a-dataframes-name-as-string#comment81424269_47237029) one can name the dataframe like this

```
apple.name = 'Apple'
```

Then get the string with `apple.name`.

```
[In]: print(apple.name) 
[Out]: Apple
```

However, assuming one wants to get the DFs from a particular label, one might as well create a dictionary with

```
dfdict = {'Apple': apple}
```

and access the dataframe via

```
[In]: print(dfdict['Apple'])
[Out]:
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```